# Play again feature issue

Tags: java

The program works the way it should but gets user's input on whether they want to play again or not and then does nothing after that. I am setting all of the original input values to 0 which is probably why. How can I get a new input from the user when they want to play again. If someone knows a better way make this program without arrays I would greatly appreciate it if you could post the code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Shapes {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("You can view any of the following shapes: ");
    System.out.print("\n1 Square");
    System.out.print("\n2 Right-angle Triangle");
    System.out.print("\n3 Pyramid");
    System.out.print("\n4 Hourglass");
    System.out.print("\n5 Diamond");

    System.out.print("\nEnter a integer to choose a shape: ");
    String shape = userInput.nextLine();

    System.out.print("\nEnter the height of the shape: ");
    int inputOne = userInput.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
    char ch = userInput.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("\n");

    do {

        if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            square(ch, inputOne);
            System.out.println();
        }

        if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
            triangle(ch, inputOne);
            System.out.println();
        }

        if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
            pyramid(ch, inputOne);
            System.out.println();
        }

        if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {
            diamond(ch, inputOne);
            System.out.println();
        }

        if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("5")) {
            hourglass(ch, inputOne);
            System.out.println();
        }
        shape = "0";
        inputOne = 0;
        ch = 0;

    } while (playAgain());
}

private static boolean playAgain() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Play again? (Y/N): ");
    String replay = keyboard.nextLine();
    return replay.equalsIgnoreCase("Y");

}

public static void square(char c, int n) {

    char[] a = new char[n];
    Arrays.fill(a, c);
    for (; n-- > 0;)
        System.out.println(a);

}

public static void triangle(char c, int n) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        char[] a = new char[i];
        Arrays.fill(a, c);
        System.out.println(a);
    }

}

public static void pyramid(char c, int n) {

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        while (true) {
            char[] s = new char[n - i - 1];
            Arrays.fill(s, ' ');
            System.out.print(s);

            char[] a = new char[i * 2 + 1];
            Arrays.fill(a, c);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }

}

public static void diamond(char c, int n) {
    boolean odd = n % 2 == 1;
    n++;
    int mid = n / 2;
    int mi = mid;
    if (odd)
        mi--;
    for (int y = 1; y < n; y++) {
        for (int x = 1; x < n; x++) {
            System.out.print((Math.abs(x + y - n) > mi || Math.abs(x - y) > mi) ? ' ' : c);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

public static void hourglass(char c, int n) {
    boolean odd = n % 2 == 1;
    if (odd)
        n++;
    int mid = n / 2;
    for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {
        if (odd && y == mid)
            continue;
        for (int x = 1; x < n; x++) {
            int a = 0;
            if (Math.abs(x + y - mid) >= mid)
                a++;
            if (Math.abs(x - y - mid) >= mid)
                a++;
            System.out.print((a % 2 == 0) ? c : ' ');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You need to retrieve the user's inputs inside the do-while loop.

Comment: @Mark How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prompt for the user input inside of the do/while loop.  Right now you are prompting the user right above the loop - so it only happens once in your code.

```
//move this stuff into the do/while
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("You can view any of the following shapes: ");
System.out.print("\n1 Square");
System.out.print("\n2 Right-angle Triangle");
System.out.print("\n3 Pyramid");
System.out.print("\n4 Hourglass");
System.out.print("\n5 Diamond");

System.out.print("\nEnter a integer to choose a shape: ");
String shape = userInput.nextLine();

System.out.print("\nEnter the height of the shape: ");
int inputOne = userInput.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
char ch = userInput.next().charAt(0);
System.out.println("\n");

do {
    ^^^^ move that stuff in here
}while(playAgain())
```

It's also worth noting that this would be easy to discover if you simply step through your code in a debugger.

Comment: If this helped solve your problem, consider marking it as 'answered'.

Answer (score 1):

You only prompt the user for input once and you set them to 0. On the next iteration of the loop, `shape` is 0 so none of the `if` statements evaluate to true and thus your program does nothing.

Retrieve the user's input inside the loop and remove zeroing-out the variables:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.print("You can view any of the following shapes: ");
        System.out.print("\n1 Square");
        System.out.print("\n2 Right-angle Triangle");
        System.out.print("\n3 Pyramid");
        System.out.print("\n4 Hourglass");
        System.out.print("\n5 Diamond");

        System.out.print("\nEnter a integer to choose a shape: ");
        String shape = userInput.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\nEnter the height of the shape: ");
        int inputOne = userInput.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
        char ch = userInput.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("\n");

        if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            square(ch, inputOne);
            System.out.println();
        }

        if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
            triangle(ch, inputOne);
            System.out.println();
        }

        if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
            pyramid(ch, inputOne);
            System.out.println();
        }

        if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {
            diamond(ch, inputOne);
            System.out.println();
        }

        if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("5")) {
            hourglass(ch, inputOne);
            System.out.println();
        }
    } while (playAgain());
}
```